# Can we get Active Directory property named Employee ID using Office365Users connector

Tags: sharepoint-online, active-directory, powerapp

Inside our active directory we have a property named "Employee ID" as follow:-

[image]

so inside our PowerApp form i want to get the value of this property,,, but i checked the Office365Users connector  @ https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/connections/connection-office365-users seems it does not provide such a data.. so how i can get the Employee ID property inside our PowerApp form? this ID is different than the ID which we can get using this formula  `Office365Users.MyProfile().Id` which will return the internal GUID of the user, and not the number shown above.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Per my test, "Get user Profile(V2)" will not retrieve the Employee ID property of the user.

EmployeeId is currently a beta feature and is only available in the beta endpoint of the [Graph API](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-beta).

Maybe you can ask for more help in graph forum:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/topics/microsoft-graph-users.html

Comment: thanks for the info .. so can i retrieve Employee ID inside PowerApp or PowerAutomate using the beta endpoint? can you explain this in more details please?

Comment: Not familiar with this, I suggest you seek better help from the experts in the dedicated forum.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Power automate to retrieve the Employee ID from AD and update a new field in SharePoint list with that employee ID.

In power automate , use Action "Get user Profile"

Comment: i tried the "Get User Profile V2".. but it will not retrieve the employee ID shown inside my screen shot

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following way to get employeeId along with other fields.

[image: MS Flow Action]